# WCF service with certificate authentication: "The caller was not authenticated by the service"

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, certificate

I'm trying to setup a WCF service with certificate-based authentication, following this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff648360.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I've followed all the steps (I think), which in summary are:
1) Generated a self-signed CA certificate and installed it as a machine-level trusted CA:

[image]

2) Generated a certificate for the service (signed by the CA certificate, `CN=QvxServiceCert`) and installed it at machine-level:

[image]

3) configured the WCF service endpoint behavior to use the certificate. My service configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="QvxServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=QvxServiceCert" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="esqQvxScheduler.Service.QvxSchedulerAPI" behaviorConfiguration="QvxServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
          name="wsHttpEndpoint" bindingName="" contract="esqQvxScheduler.Service.IQvxSchedulerAPI" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/QvxSchedulerAPI/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

4) Generated a certificate for the client (again, signed by the CA certificate, this one has `CN=QvxClientCert`) and installed at user-level:

[image]

5) configured the WCF client behavior to use it for authentication. This is my client config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="qvxClientBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate findValue="CN=QvxClientCert" />
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsHttpEndpoint">
                    <security>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/QvxSchedulerAPI/" binding="wsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="qvxClientBehavior"
                bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="QvxSchedulerAPI.IQvxSchedulerAPI"
                name="wsHttpEndpoint">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="[A LONG AUTOGENERATED STRING THE MEANING OF WHICH I HAVE NO IDEA]" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

6) Gave the user that runs the client access to the certificate, by issuing the following on the command line: `cacls "C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-742627442-1779984360-2302642487-1000" /E /G "MyUser-PC\MyUsername":R`

This was all done following the guide, without any issue that I could see. Everything seems ok... but when I try to invoke the service from my client, all I get this frustratingly vague and unhelpful exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TlsnegoTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a lot of trial and error, turns out that you either have to have a CRL installed for your CA or you have to specify explicitly that you don't want a revocation check, by adding this to your behavior's ClientCredentials tag:

```
<serviceCertificate>
    <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
</serviceCertificate>
```

and vice-versa for the service side:

```
<clientCertificate>
    <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
</clientCertificate>
```

Also, you need to remove the autogenerated certificate tag in the client and replace it with an instruction to look up the certificate:

```
<identity>
    <certificateReference findValue="CN=QvxServiceCert" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</identity>
```